# How can I get `cacafire` to show up in the original gnome-terminal, instead of a separate window?

Tags: terminal, x11, gnome-terminal

If I am in a Linux virtual terminal (pressing `Control-Alt-F1` on Ubuntu), and I use the command `cacafire`, I get the flames inside the actual terminal.

However, if I am in the gnome environment, and I start a terminal and run `cacafire`, I get a separate window popping up that displays the fire.

How can I force it to display the fire in the same terminal that it is run from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `man` doesn't seem to have a option to control it. But you can use `DISPLAY= cacafire` and cacafire wouldn't know how to connect to your `X` server; then fallback to running in the current terminal.

Comment: This works for `aafire`, but for `cacafire`, it says "Failed to initialize libcaca"

Comment: @merlin2011 That sounds like a bug, but it does indeed work. https://asciinema.org/a/8070

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the environment variable `DISPLAY` has no value, for example run `DISPLAY= cacafire`